# 2 identical log files in eclipse liberty server?

Tags: eclipse, logging, websphere-liberty

Small issue, but I was curious if anyone knows why eclipse shows 2 different log consoles when there's only 1 liberty server running?

As shown in the screenshot, clicking the 'Display selected console' button will show 2 different log consoles, each with a different name (WebSphere Application Server Liberty on 1 and wlp8559 on the other).  I was wondering if there's a way to specify only 1 log console given they both seem to log exactly the same server output.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe you just added same server twice in the `Servers` view :-)). Ensure that you have only one Liberty server in the servers.

Answer (score 0):

You've created at least two different instances of Liberty servers, one where the WDT Server name field is "WebSphere Application Server Liberty at localhost" and one where that field is "wlp8559".  From the Console menu labels, you can tell that you started each of them at different times, but you can't tell if they're based on the same runtime or not.  You would have to look at the Servers tab to do so.  Based on the Console menu, Eclipse thinks they're both running (there would be  in front of the server name if they has been stopped), but unless you've changed the port numbers in server config, that's not possible.  You may not find both of the servers listed in the Servers tab if you've deleted either, doing so would leave the output on the Console tab though.